# How to put many <div> inside <details> and style it?

Tags: html, css

My current UI with styles

[image: how it lookes]

I need those divs to be in a row with a gap. `display: flex` has no effect on details

```css
.block_desc {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 180px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block_desc_count {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.block_desc__desc {
  text-align: center;
}

details {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<details open="">
  <div class="block_desc"><span class="block_desc_count">0</span>
    <p class="block_desc_desc">number of words you have guessed correctly</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block_desc"><span class="block_desc_count">4</span>
    <p class="block_desc_desc">number of words you have guessed correctly</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block_desc"><span class="block_desc_count">100</span>
    <p class="block_desc_desc">number of words you have guessed correctly</p>
  </div>
  <summary>19:4 / 2.9.2022</summary>
</details>
```

Comment: Could you share your CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the cards with a div and style that as display: flex. Widgets such as `details` don't behave like div elements.

```css
.block_desc {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 180px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

block_desc_count {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

block_desc__desc {
  text-align: center;
}

details .container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<details open="">
  <summary>19:4 / 2.9.2022</summary>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block_desc"><span class="block_desc_count">0</span>
      <p class="block_desc_desc">number of words you have guessed correctly</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block_desc"><span class="block_desc_count">4</span>
      <p class="block_desc_desc">number of words you have guessed correctly</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block_desc"><span class="block_desc_count">100</span>
      <p class="block_desc_desc">number of words you have guessed correctly</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`detail` goes along with `summary` which is messed up with your `div` elements.

You can wrap your `div` elements into another `div` as a container and apply a flexbox on that container element instead.

```
.block_container {
  margin-top: 10px; /*Create a top gap*/
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px; /*Gap for flex items*/
}
```

```css
.block_desc {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 180px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block_desc_count {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.block_desc_desc {
  text-align: center;
}

.block_container {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<details open="">
  <div class="block_container">
  <div class="block_desc"><span class="block_desc_count">0</span>
    <p class="block_desc_desc">number of words you have guessed correctly</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block_desc"><span class="block_desc_count">4</span>
    <p class="block_desc_desc">number of words you have guessed correctly</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block_desc"><span class="block_desc_count">100</span>
    <p class="block_desc_desc">number of words you have guessed correctly</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <summary>19:4 / 2.9.2022</summary>
</details>
```